# Determine every number in the interval $[0,10]$ such that $F(x)=\cot(\pi x)$ is undefined

Tags: calculus

Determine every number in the interval $[0,10]$ such that $F(x)=\cot(\pi x)$ is undefined. Justify your reasoning.

Please help this is on my calc homework and I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Recall that $\cot t=\dfrac{\cos t}{\sin t}$.

The cotangent of $\pi x$ is therefore  undefined when $\sin( \pi x)=0$. Note that $\sin t=0$ when $t=0,\pm \pi,\pm 2\pi,\pm 3\pi,\dots$.

**Remark:** I am assuming that by cot(pi)(x) you mean $\cot(\pi x)$. If you mean $(\cot(\pi))(x)$ then the function is everywhere undefined.